# What's the benefit of using call / apply over calling the function directly?

Tags: javascript

For instance, say I have

```
var numbers = [5, 6, 2, 3, 7];

var max = Math.max.apply(null, numbers);

console.log(max);
```

or,

```
var numbers = [5, 6, 2, 3, 7];

var max = Math.max.call(null, ...numbers);

console.log(max);
```

Why would I choose `call` or `apply` over something similar to the below?

```
var numbers = [5, 6, 2, 3, 7];

var max = Math.max(...numbers);

console.log(max);
```

I've been able to get away with coding in Javascript without using either of these two methods (or `bind`) but I'd like to know if I should start using them.

Comment: Use it when you need to set the calling context (the `this`) inside the called function. It's often not so useful anymore since we have arrow functions and parameter spread syntax

Comment: The first one using `apply()` would work in ES5 environments where spread operator not supported. No benefit using first two over last one when `thisArg` is null and spread supported

Comment: @CertainPerformance ...or when you want to curry. As a silly off-the-top-of-my-head example, `foo[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick.bind(this, i))`...

Comment: One of the uses of `call` is to convert an array-like item to array: `[].slice.call(<array like>)`

Comment: IMHO not precisely a duplicate. Keep in mind that if you don't need to set the `this` value, there's no reason to use `call` or `apply`, you can use the spread syntax right in the call expression. Using `call` with the spread syntax: `someFunction.call(obj, ...args);` doesn't make sense, you can use `apply` and pass the array of arguments directly.